# Define a circle of diameter $5$ anywhere on the plane. Then define a triangle inside the circle with a maximum height of $5$..

Tags: geometry

Let $V$ be a  $2$ dimensional plane. Define a circle of diameter $5$ anywhere on the plane. Denote it by $C$. Then define a triangle inside the circle with a maximum height of $5$. Denote it by $T$. If a genie chooses a point, P, inside the circle, what is the probability that it lies in the triangle?

Please help, I am confused. How do I begin? Do I just assume that they are at the origin? I know what vector spaces and triangles are. *I have a feeling that we should use binomial distribution, but I am not sure

Comment: I'm having difficulty picturing a triangle *inside* a circle with maximum height equal to the circle's diameter.

Comment: You just need to find the area of the circle and the area of the triangle, and compare the two. I agree with @Fimpellizieri that this problem isn't particularly well specified - there are an infinite number of triangles with a maximum height of 5, so the area of *T* is not defined. Many of those triangles don't even fit inside the circle, but there are still an infinite number of triangles that do. I guess the most likely interpretation is that we have an equilateral triangle circumscribed by a circle of radius 5, but there's nothing that actually indicates that's the case.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri It probably meant that the circle can be of any size inside the circle.

Comment: Probability $ = \dfrac{\text{Area of the Triangle}}{\text{Area of the circle}}$

Comment: sorry I meant radius 5

Comment: What would the maximum possible area be for a triangle with max height 5? that lies in the circle (radius 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many triangles with height $5$ and we know that the maximum base should be less than $10$ (otherwise it would go outside our circle). Then the area of a triangle is $\frac{(10)(5)}{2}$ and the area of our circle is $25 \pi$. We divide those two to get our value. Which is $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

A sample circle:
[image]

(please ignore the markings on the side). So we selected the maximum height possible and tried to find the maximum base. We found a triangle with base $10$ and no bigger base is possible as the diameter of our circle is $10$.

(I used sketchpad 5.1 for the drawing).

Comment: why cant the hieght be bigger?

Comment: The diameter is defined as the longest distance possible between two points on the circle.